# Many to Many Relationship laravel Column x Row from database [pivot]

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many

Get Column from customertypes table , and show value from customerprices table with lastest one only. how to get last value from pivot table.

```
***customertypes tbl***
| id | name      |
| 1 | Retail     |
| 2 | Whole Sale |

***pricelevels tbl***
| id  | name      |
| 1   | Level A   |
| 2   | Level B   |
| 3   | Level C   |

***customerprices tbl***
| id |pricelevels_id |customertypes_id | amount | created_at
| 1  |  1            | 1               | 1000    | 22-12-2020
| 1  |  1            | 1               | 1100    | 22-12-2022
| 1  |  1            | 2               |  900    | 22-12-2022


Expected Result 

 level name | Retail | Whole Sale | ....
 Level A    | 1100   | 900
 Level B    | null   | null
 Level C    | null   | null

$price_levels = PriceLevel::with('customerprice')->get();
```

Comment: can you update the code you tried ? so that we can help

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

this might help you

Comment: it is laravel 10. and i already read carefully that pivot many 2 many relationshiop

Comment: which version of laravel is used in this case?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qEXEYwKvnKNt49LBuwyJjP/0#&togetherjs=Saek6qca3z

Comment: Try this solution from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many). Disclaimer: Can't tell for 100% it would work for you because eloquent standard naming convention wasn't followed strictly. 
Idea is to make another relation in `PriceLevel` model class.